# Dividing a RelativeLayout into two halves

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I have created a RelativeLayout containing 2 buttons, a radio button and a graph view.

I want to display two different data in graph now.

How do I split the RelativeLayout into two halves?

This is my present XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnStart"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:text="SlaveEnable" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnStop"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/BtnStart"
        android:text="SlaveDisable" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/BtnSaveFile"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/BtnStop"
        android:text="SaveFile" />

    <helog.diwesh.NugaBest.GraphView
        android:id="@+id/gview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/BtnStart"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I did not get question here? What exactly you want to do? do you want to add two graphs in screen, both occupying equal space ? or you can upload sample drawing showing desired layout.

Comment: Yes my present layout is  a relative  layout with a  graphview showing ECG signals in wave  form . I want to now divide this graph into half and in the other half  show the signals of respiration . Three buttons are there at the bottom which should be there at the same place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this layout. This should work with some changes if not perfect. This will add two graphs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnStart"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:text="SlaveEnable" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnStop"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/BtnStart"
        android:text="SlaveDisable" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/BtnSaveFile"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/BtnStop"
        android:text="SaveFile" />

<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/BtnStart"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <helog.diwesh.NugaBest.GraphView
                android:id="@+id/gview1"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <helog.diwesh.NugaBest.GraphView
                android:id="@+id/gview2"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks something similar . But the first rouble is that the two graphviews are like vertically but I require horizontal like screen divided into two . Also both the graphs are looking exactly duplicate copies of each other . There Is something like values on the first graph but I want to put something else on the canvas . eg : my graphview comprised of HR and  temperature on the canvas , now I want to paste the Respiratory details on the canvas .

Comment: @RahulSharma: Can draw simple sketch of desired layout and upload? it will be easier to understand.

Comment: I know @sagar but unfortunately I don't have  enough reputation points to paste a screenhot as I am new .......But let me try to show something in text                                                                    ----------------------------------------------------------          graphview1 : temperature                                                           ---------------------------------------------------------------        graphview2 : respiration                                                          --------------------------------------------------------------     3 button

Comment: @RahulSharma : when we ask question there is option in top bar of editor to add image. I don't think it has reputation restriction.

Comment: Thanks  a ton brother . Ok and  I checked it takes 10 reputation points to add image . Now the trouble is that the two graphviews are replica of each other . The upper one is fine but the lower one should have  a different caption there ... Also in my class file on which I created the first canvas object mcanvas  , can it be simply corporated by creating another canvas  object mcanvas2 and pointing my Graphview to gview2 like   mGraphView = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.gview2);

Comment: I tried running your layout but it just gives me a  blank black screen and  I see some signal running at the very bottom where the buttons are

Comment: @RahulSharma: it should work by creating another canvas object as you said.

Comment: :it is unfortunately not displaying even the previous data ... The layout in output has  gone completely blank

Comment: @RahulSharma: I do not have android setup on my machine so can not simulate this layout here. It is difficult to say what went wrong. Try giving different background color to buttons and linear layout. It will show exactly how much space is occupied by that element.

Comment: I do see a  small graphical line  going just below where the buttons are ..... but I think it is hidden behind the three buttons below .

Comment: Suppose if I am able to see the graph , is there a  way that I can save  a  history of it everytime  I run my application ?

Comment: @RahulSharma : Consider asking different question. This is out of scope of current question.

Answer (score 19):

So, for this, the best way I've found (which feels like a total hack, but works like a charm) is to have a zero-size View aligned to the center of the layout, then align the left half to the left of that View, the align the right half to the right of that View. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/anchor"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/left_side"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/anchor"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:text="Left Side" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/right_side"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/anchor"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:text="Right Side" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi thanks I tried this but it gave  me the following error : error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_toRightOf' with value 'anchor').

Comment: Fixed. Just forgot the ID, but that's a common one you should be able to check into.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I removed the `RelativeLayout` with `LinearLayout` for using `layout_weight`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".50" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnStart"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:text="SlaveEnable" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnStop"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:text="SlaveDisable" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/BtnSaveFile"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SaveFile" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".50" >

        <helog.diwesh.NugaBest.GraphView
            android:id="@+id/gview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply @ Ye Lin Aung .... But when I paste your code and  see in the graphical layout . I see no changes .

Comment: Hi thanks I got the following error : The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

Comment: fixed again. you can try.

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts . It worked very close to what I required . I have  to though put the graphview on the top and  the buttons at the bottom , which I was able to manage  by just reversing your code . however my other half comes out to be  a simple layout . How to make that other half also look like  a graphview ?

Comment: you mean the below path also a graphview ?

Comment: Yes please , the one below should also be  a graph view